# m4a file receives no status code when loading on iPad (HTTPS)

Tags: android, html, ios, https

I am trying to use HTML5 audio across devices and have managed to get it to work on desktop machines by using the following code:

```
<audio id="audio-1" preload="auto" >
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file1.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<audio id="audio-2"  preload="auto">
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file2.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<audio id="audio-3" preload="auto">
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file3.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="~/Assets/audio/file3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

However on devices (both Android 5.1.1 and iOS 9) the sounds don't play.

When debugging the iPad I noticed that GET requests were sent for all the audio files but no status code was returned.

[image: iPad Safari debug screen]
I have read an article from IBM about a combination of AAC and OGG are the best source of cross browser compatibility: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#resources so I'm hopeful that it isn't the file types causing the issue.

I've also read that there are possible issues with files being served up over HTTPS on devices.

What I don't know is if there is a work around to get these files to play on devices? (They are triggered on events using native HTML5 audio methods in JS)

Answer (score 0):

I have since found out that you cannot autoplay sounds on mobile devices. You have to have a user interaction such as a button press to instigate the action.

http://codetheory.in/fixing-html5-audio-problems-in-ios-and-android-mobile-browsers-to-overcome-the-limitations/